# How to decide whether one class is a cohesive part vs dependency of another class (In terms of unit testing)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, refactoring, decoupling

I'm working on a project that was not designed with unit testing in mind.

Since inside of `StartWorking()` method I create a new instance of `WorkYear` and call `year.RecalculateAllTime()`, is `WorkYear` class considered to be an external dependency (in terms of unit testing)?

Or since the `Employee` bound to `WorkYear` by composition relationship + `Employee` is meant to perform actions on WorkYears, are the `Employee` and `WorkYear` form a cohesive entity where both classes aren't considered as dependencies of one another?

In other words, should `StartWorking(...)` method be tested in isolation from `WorkYear` class?

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    private List<WorkYear> _workYears;
    private readonly IntervalCalculator _intervalCalculator;
    // Other fields...

    protected Employee(IntervalCalculator intervalCalculator)
    {
        _intervalCalculator = intervalCalculator;
        WorkYears = new List<WorkYear>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<WorkYear> WorkYears
    {
        get => _workYears.AsReadOnly();
        private set => _workYears = value.ToList();
    }
    // Other properties...
    

    public void StartWorking(DateTime joinedCompany)
    {
        List<PayPeriodInterval> allIntervals = _intervalCalculator.GenerateIntervalsFor(joinedCompany.Date.Year);

        PayPeriodInterval currentInterval = allIntervals.Find(i => i.StartDate <= joinedCompany && joinedCompany <= i.EndDate);
        
        PayPeriod firstPeriod = CalculateFirstPeriod(joinedCompany, currentInterval);

        // There is a possibility that employee worked during this year and returned during
        // the same exact year or even month. That is why we are trying to find this year in database:
        WorkYear year = WorkYears.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CurrentYear == joinedCompany.Year);

        if (year == null)
        {
            // Create new year with current and future periods.
            year = new WorkYear(joinedCompany.Year, this, new List<PayPeriod> {firstPeriod});

            AddYear(year);
        }
        else
        {
            // There is a possibility that employee left and got back during the same period.
            // That is why we should try to find this period so that we don't override it with new one:
            PayPeriod existingPeriod = year.GetPeriodByDate(joinedCompany);

            if (existingPeriod != null)
            {
                var oldCurrentPeriodWorktime = new TimeSpan(existingPeriod.WorktimeHours, existingPeriod.WorktimeMinutes, 0);

                firstPeriod = CalculateFirstPeriod(joinedCompany, currentInterval, oldCurrentPeriodWorktime);
            }

            year.PayPeriods.Add(firstPeriod);
        }

        List<PayPeriodInterval> futureIntervals = allIntervals.FindAll(i => currentInterval.EndDate < i.StartDate);

        List<PayPeriod> futurePeriods = NewPeriods(futureIntervals);

        year.PayPeriods.AddRange(futurePeriods);

        year.RecalculateAllTime();
    }

    public abstract List<PayPeriod> NewPeriods(List<PayPeriodInterval> intervals);

    public void AddYear(WorkYear workYear) => _workYears.Add(workYear);

    protected abstract PayPeriod CalculateFirstPeriod(DateTime firstDayAtWork, PayPeriodInterval firstPeriodInerval, TimeSpan initialTime = default);

    // Other methods...

}

public class WorkYear
{
    public WorkYear(int currentYear, Employee employee, List<PayPeriod> periods)
    {
        Employee = employee;
        EmployeeId = employee.Id;
        CurrentYear = currentYear;
        PayPeriods = periods ?? new List<PayPeriod>();

        foreach (PayPeriod period in PayPeriods)
        {
            period.WorkYear = this;
            period.WorkYearId = Id;
        }
    }

    public int EmployeeId { get; }
    public int CurrentYear { get; }
    public Employee Employee { get; }
    public List<PayPeriod> PayPeriods { get; set; }
    
    // Other roperties...


    public void RecalculateAllTime()
    {
        //Implementation Logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not consider `WorkYear` to be an external dependency. It appears to be operating more like a model.

Comment: Does calling the members of `WorkYear` have any behavioral side effects to the `Employee` class?

Comment: I a potential circular dependency here a WorkYear explicitly depends on Employee.

Comment: @Nkosi I'm not sure what you meant by _"behavoral side effects"_ but methods in `WorkYear` do not affect state of `Employee` class. `WorkYear` however uses some of `Employee` data(read only) to perform other calculations.

Comment: The circular dependency will wreak havoc if you ever serialized an `Employee` but otherwise is fine.

Comment: @НикитаУрюпин Then I do not foresee any major issues with the design you have present. You can consider refactoring the calculation functionality into a single purpose service (SRP) but I guess that is outside of the scope of the asked question.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET In my case there is one to many relationship between `Employee` and `WorkYear`. That is not considered a circular dependency as far as I know...

Comment: But WorkYear has `public Employee Employee { get; }` . Its circular :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It's outside of scope of this topic but now I'm paranoied about circular dependency.  :(((  Isn't that how it should be? `Employee` must belong to a `WorkYear`, otherwise specific workyear shouldn't exist without related employee. Also, I'm using EF6 as an ORM and it's using those "circular dependencies" to load related objects.

Comment: EF in general is brutal with regards to circular dependency. Keep in mind you don't *have* to define both sides of the relationship (it will still figure it out). Also serializing EF objects is a terrible idea; you always want a API layer that doesn't have the circular piece. That said; its fine for what you are doing. Just don't serialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Super big caveat: This stuff gets really opinionated really fast. There are lots of valid designs!

Okay, now that I've said that. DTO's (Data transfer objects) are not external dependencies. You don't inject them.

`WorkYear` has all the hallmarks of a DTO (other than that method). I think you are OK as is. Because it has that `RecalculateAllTime` method it should *also* be unit tested however. An example of an external dependency in this case would be something that *fetches* the list of work years.

The basic rule of thumb is:

- You compose data (DTOs)
- You inject behavior (services)

Comment: Then in my case the `IntervalCalculator` class is a good example of injecting behavior, since it's not a POCO. Thank you for your answer, it helped me to clear things up!

Comment: @НикитаУрюпин Correct; but I would put it behind an interface so its easier to mock in your test

Comment: I’m sorry if I sound really pedantic, but a DTO is not the same as a POCO. A [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) is a (behaviorless) class that is used to carry data between processes. A [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object), on the other hand, is a class that has no dependency on any dependency on an external framework. It can contain behavior, but is not used to transfer data between processes.

Comment: @Steven Interesting; I've probably been using POCO wrong then! Removed that piece

Comment: To be honest with you, while helping Mark Seemann with the second edtion of his book, he rightfully corrected me on making the same mistake. I've been using those terms incorrectly myself for years.